# Is the Nikon Df discontinued

Tags: nikon-df

I have seen some conflicting information on the web, some sites saying that the [Nikon Df](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikon_Df) is discontinued (as of 2016), and others saying no. Is it discontinued or not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we've decided that speculative questions like this aren't a good fit for the site. Plus, this is an inherently transient question. One could simply answer "Yes. (If this answer is not yet true, please wait a bit.)"

Comment: @mattdm I changed it to have a specific time. There is nothing "speculative" about it. Either it is discontinued or not as of 2016.

Comment: While the edit does make it specific to a time, @mattdm's point stands. Do we need a "Is the Df discontinued (as of 2017)?" question, and one for 2018, etc.? The nature of the question is such, that at some point, the camera will be discontinued, and the question will need to be edited to make it "permanent" or "timely", thus invalidating the one answer. Stack Exchange isn't really suited to cataloging or maintaining this type of data.

Comment: It is speculative at this point in time.

Comment: @mattdm not according to Philip Kendall. He thinks it is definitely still a distributed product, just limited production. I am actually planning to accept his answer, if no better answer appears.

Comment: But read the rest of his answer. It's fairly common for websites to still list cameras which see internally discontinued, which may be the case here, *but no one but Nikon knows*.

Comment: With most electronics, there is not much of an announcement to avoid hindering sales of existing stock. The company usually ends production long before (easily a year or more) it is discontinued and even that status is introduced at different times depending on the market, even if production ceases at the factory.

Comment: Let's take this one back a bit: why do you care if its "discontinued", whatever that actually means? If the Df meets your needs, you buy it, if it doesn't, you don't. Even if there is a hypothetical "Df 2" on the way, it will be significantly more expensive than the current price of the Df.

Comment: @PhilipKendall There are a lot of accessories for it, and I am concerned that if it is discontinued, some of the accessories might become unavailable by also being discontinued. So, if I buy the Df, then I might have the problem of not being able to buy all of its accessories.

Comment: Luckily, in the camera world, especially amongst the big 2 (Canon and Nikon), _very few_ accessories are very strictly camera model dependent, and even those that are, are in the marketplace for quite awhile, even after the camera is out of production. About the only accessories that are so model specific are custom-fit cases (such as form-fit leather cases) and arca swiss-style mounting plates, L-plates, and the like. Everything else is usually interchangeable. Accessories should be the last consideration in your mind when choosing a camera.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Nikon's European site still lists the Df on their [list of SLR cameras](http://www.europe-nikon.com/en_GB/products/category_pages/digital_cameras/category_SLR.page) and the [Df page itself](http://www.europe-nikon.com/en_GB/product/digital-cameras/slr/professional/df) says:

> Available at selected retailers

If you're asking us to speculate whether Nikon have made an internal decision to discontinue the Df which hasn't been made public, that's not something Stack Exchange is the right place to be asking.